# str_replace add to beginning of string $var = str_replace('.*','#.*',$string); regex hashtags

Tags: regex, str-replace, hashtag

I'm trying to add a hashtag (#) to the start of a string so that:

```
string
```

looks like

```
#string
```

How can I do this with str_replace or another form of regex?

```
 $string = str_replace('*','*#',$string);
```

Thank you. :)

**Solution:**

```
$re = "/^/m"; 
$subst = "#"; 
$string = preg_replace($re, $subst, $string);
```

**Edit: As shown by user:vks, this worked! Thanks vks :)**

Comment: start of which string?

Comment: `$new_var = '#' . $var` ???

Comment: You mean a Number sign (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign). Hashtags are a string of characters starting with a Number sign that originated on Twitter to make searching topics easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^
```

You can use this and replace by `#`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eX9gK2/5

```
$re = "/^/m"; 
$str = "string "; 
$subst = "#"; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Comment: `str_replace` present in php and it won't accept regex.

Comment: Bug? You need to use preg_replace.

Comment: That's beautiful. Thank you buddy. Regex101.com looks like a great site for me to check out as well now that I'm dabbling in regex. Seems like a jsfiddle for the language. I appreciate the recommendation and code, you rock.